# Relationship schemata caused in childhood - better term for this, and can they be grouped?

Tags: psychology

I listen to a podcast (by Stefanie Stahl, in German), where a psychologist tries to explain the problems adult guests describe to her. She often finds reasons for their problems in the guests childhood, in how their caretakers treated them. For example, someone who always had to fight to be loved (who only felt conditionally loved), might then later on look for partners who also only conditionally accept them. And as soon as a relationship is stable, they might not find their partner interesting any more.

Basically, the idea is that during childhood you learn how relationships work, and later gravitate to what feels familiar (but might be unhealthy).

I am wondering:

a) Does this have a basis in a specific psychological theory? I'm aware of
the [Strange Situation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strange_situation) test and the attachment styles, but the
examples in the podcast seem more specific, not just "doesn't attach", "attaches", "clingy", but affecting what one tends to attach to (supposedly).

b) Is there a name for relationship problem schemata that are
'caused' by what one experienced in childhood?

c) In case there is a basis for this at all: Is there a grouping for those schemata (the different ways in which ones relationship style can be broken because of childhood experiences)? A type of overview?

I hope I'm making sense in what I'm describing.